# How are the "Cloud Services" created for Virtual Machines and Azure Cloud Services related?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

When you create an Azure VM, it has to be placed into a Cloud Service (either new or existing).

Is that the exact same logical structure as an Azure Cloud Service that's created when deploying Web and Worker roles via Visual Studio?

Can I deploy Roles from VS into a Cloud Service created via VM creation?  I can deploy a VM into a Cloud Service created via VS deployment?  If either of those are true, how does that "free-standing" VM relate to the Role VMs?  Is it just floating inside the Cloud Service independently from the Role VMs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really should be on ServerFault, and the question will likely be closed, but...

Treat "cloud service" as a wrapper around *either* a collection of web and worker role instances *or* a collection of Virtual Machines, behind a single `xyz.cloudapp.net` namespace. Both are equivalent to the outside world (that is, accessing a service+endpoint via `xyz.cloudapp.net:port`). But managed differently.

Virtual Machines cannot be mixed with web/worker role instances in the same cloud service.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer David.  

If a mod wants to move it I understand, or I can re-ask over there.